# Characterizing the rationalization of spaces.

Tags: homotopy-theory, rational-homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, model-categories

In the category of rational spaces, loop spaces split as products of Eilenberg-Mac Lane
spaces and SUSPENSIONS split as wedges of (rational) spheres.  I wonder if anything of the following form is true:

(*)  Any functor $F$ from spaces to spaces which splits suspensions and loop spaces as above must factor through the rationalization.

EDIT 1:  Greg raises some fine questions, but I stand by my wording.  This is a question that arises from curiosity, not because I need it for anything, so I'd be happy with "anything like" the given statement.

EDIT 2:  At least for simply-connected spaces, rationalization commutes with loop and suspension.  But, it seems to me that the power of the property is that the suspension
of any F-space splits and the loops of any F-space splits.  So I would go with:
the suspension of any rational space splits as a wedge of rational spheres and 
the loops of any rational space splits as a product of rational Eilenberg-Mac Lanes spaces.

Thus, we'd be looking for functors to some model-esque category with some relatively manageable list of objects whose products exhaust the homotopy types of loop spaces and whose wedges exhaust the homotopy types of suspensions.

Comment: Do you mean that rationally a <i> suspension </i> splits as a wedge of <i> rationalized </i> spheres? And can you say more precisely what property you want F to have? Do you mean that F of a suspension should be equivalent to a wedge of spaces of the form F(Sphere)? Or may be F(wedge of spheres)? Would the constant functor that sends every space to the circle be an example?

Comment: I guess your constant functor is an example, and it does factor through rationalization.

Comment: Leave the question a little vague, sure, but Greg's initial question is about your initial statement, not your question.

The rationalization functor applied to the loop space of X is always equivalent to a product of (rational) Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, yes?

The rationalization functor applied to the <i>suspension</i> of X is always equivalent to a wedge of rationalized spheres, yes?


Comment: In particular, consider the rationalization of CP^\infty \vee CP^\infty.  It is not a rational wedge of spheres.  Please do change or <strike> your very first line and your initial question (*) (as you seem to be trying to do with EDIT 2, but that makes things hard to read without deleting/<strike>ing incorrect statements above.)  By the way, I think the question you are getting at, as I understand it, is interesting and something along those lines seems likely to be true.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see the think-o for so long.  Fixed now.

Comment: The homotopy theory of rational spaces is such that every loop object is an infinite loop object; in this world a space is a spectrum with some extra structure, and looping just once destroys that structure. Dually, spheres ought to be "infinite suspension objects". I don't see how to make abstract sense of this.

Answer (score 3):

I have an answer.

Look at $f$-localization functors $L_f$.  The restriction of $L_f$ to simply-connected spaces is rationalization if and only if the following three conditions hold:

1. $L_f(S^2)$ is nontrivial and simply-connected
2. $L_f$ commutes with cofiber sequences of simply-connected finite complexes
3. if $X$ is a simply-connected finite complex, then for large enough $k$, $\Sigma^k L_f(X)$ splits as a wedge of copies of $L_f(S^n)$ for various values of $n$.

Details can be found here:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2140

Answer (score 3):

I think the following is a trivial counterexample, which may lead you to reflect about your question:

\begin{align*}
F\colon  Spaces & \longrightarrow Spaces\\\\
X&\;\mapsto\;\bigvee_{H_1(X,\mathbb{F}_2)}S^1
\end{align*}

This functor takes **any** space to a wedge of several circles, one circle for each element in the homology group ${H_1(X,{\mathbb{F}}_{2})}$. Such wedges are both suspensions and Eilenberg-MacLane spaces. Obviously this functor does not factor through rationalization, since there are spaces $X$ and $Y$ with $X\simeq _{\mathbb{Q}} Y$ but $|H_1(X,\mathbb{F}_2)|\neq |H_1(Y,\mathbb{F}_2)|$.

Of course, you can replace $H_1$ with $H_n$ for any $n$ if you wish to work with simply connected spaces.

Comment: This is not a localization and it does not commute with cofiber sequences. For example, apply it to $S^1 \to * \to S^2$.

Comment: That didn't seem to be a requirement of your question.

Comment: Fernando: a small point, to see that your construction is really a functor, it might be clearer to write it as $X\mapsto \Sigma (H_1(X;{\Bbb F}_2))_+$.

Comment: @John: nice remark!

Comment: @Jeff: Fernando is correct. You do not require the condition that the functor commutes with cofiber sequences.

Comment: My question was (explicitly) intended to be open-ended.  Your example clearly shows that the stated splitting conditions are not enough to force $F$ to factor through rationalization.

Comment: @Fernando:   Since I had just posted my answer, I misunderstood your saying that $F$ was a counterexample to (*) as saying that it was a counterexample to my answer.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Jeff: it would help, I think (at least for me), if you framed your post in question form, rather than making a statement (*).